# Segmentation fault in expression template using type created with auto keyword

Tags: c++, c++11, segmentation-fault, auto, expression-templates

I am constructing code with expression templates for computational kernels. My question is very short: Why does GNU G++ give a segfault (4.9.1, compiled with -O3) on the line containing the `+=` in the following example:

```
// Like this it crashes
auto expression = Ix_h( Ix(u) );
ut += expression;
```

But not when I type the equivalent code:

```
// But like this it does not
ut += Ix_h( Ix(u) );
```

Both Clang and Intel work fine.

I have added the entire code below. Sorry for the length, it was the shortest example I could create:

```
struct Grid
{
  Grid(const int itot, const int gc) :
    itot(itot), gc(gc), istart(gc), iend(itot+gc), icells(itot+2*gc) {}

  const int itot;
  const int gc;
  const int istart;
  const int iend;
  const int icells;
};

template<int loc, class Inner>
struct Interp
{
  Interp(const Inner& inner) : inner_(inner) {}

  const Inner& inner_;

  inline double operator()(const int i) const
  {
    return   (-1./16)*(inner_(i + (-2+loc)) + inner_(i + ( 1+loc)))
           + ( 9./16)*(inner_(i + (-1+loc)) + inner_(i + (   loc)));
  }
};

template<class Inner>
inline Interp<1, Inner> Ix(const Inner& inner)
{ return Interp<1, Inner>(inner); }

template<class Inner>
inline Interp<0, Inner> Ix_h(const Inner& inner)
{ return Interp<0, Inner>(inner); }

class Field
{
  public:
    Field(const Grid& grid) :
      grid_(grid),
      data_(new double[grid_.icells]) {}

    inline double operator()(const int i) const
    { return data_[i]; }

    inline double& operator()(const int i)
    { return data_[i]; }

    template<class T>
    inline Field& operator+=(const T& expression)
    {
      for (int i=grid_.istart; i<grid_.iend; ++i)
        (*this)(i) += expression(i);

      return *this;
    }

  private:
    const Grid& grid_;
    double* data_;
};

int main()
{
  Grid grid(256, 4);

  Field u (grid);
  Field ut(grid);

  // Like this it crashes
  auto expression = Ix_h( Ix(u) );
  ut += expression;

  // But like this it does not
  ut += Ix_h( Ix(u) );

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're probably running into an undefined behaviour scenario. Gdb would be your best bet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
auto expression = Ix_h( Ix(u) );
```

Here, `Ix(u)` creates a temporary that is bound to the reference to the converting constructor `Interp<0, Interp<1, Field>>::Interp(Inner const&)`. The constructor initializes the reference `inner_` to the object. You now have a reference to a temporary value that will be destructed at the end of the full expression `Ix_h( Ix(u) )`.

The reason it works when you do `ut += Ix_h( Ix(u) )` is because the reference as well as the temporary dies at the end of the expression. Initializing `expression` simply hands off the reference. Then using `ut += expression` uses an object which has since died, which is undefined behavior.

Solution: Make `inner_` an object rather than a reference so a copy occurs:

```
Inner inner_;
```

Comment: I see your point, but that would only work in a practical way if the base object (the `Field` class) is simple, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Chiel If copies will be excessive and are expensive, consider move-semantics. Have `Interp` takes its argument by rvalue-reference and initialize `inner_` by doing `: inner_(std::move(inner))`. This requires `Inner` to implement move-semantics. Otherwise you're fine. You shouldn't worry about performance until you've profiled and discovered bottlenecks in your program.

Comment: If I use move semantics, how do I keep track over the entire tree, once the overloaded compound assignment expands all the operator() calls?

Comment: @Chiel I'm not sure what you mean by "keep track over the entire tree". What concern do you have over move-semantics affecting that?

Comment: If I move the references, I lose the link to my inner type, don't I? If I try this on my full code, it does not work. I will read into it, because I am not sure I fully understand what `std::move` does. Your help has been great, thanks a lot.